# How to display DOCX document in Android

Tags: android

I am facing issue while parsing and displaying DOCX document in Android. I am new in this. I have tried parsing docx in java using Apache POI and it works fine. Its little heavy as it needs a lot of jars to execute the code. Below is the sample code in Java:

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(docPath); 
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument(OPCPackage.open(fis));
XWPFWordExtractor extractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(document);
System.out.println(extractor.getText());
```

It displays the input stream.

In case of Android I am facing isssue. It gives error like duplicate xmlbeans stuff in xmlBean jar. I read about it that Android is very strict about duplicate files and it produces issue while java not. On top, Apache POI is little bulky as well as it contanis lot of jars and takes alot of space. i am looking for a simple solution for this.

Please help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to show your `docx file`  into `WebView` , instead you can use **AndroidDocxToHtml** library , here is the link below:-

https://github.com/plutext/AndroidDocxToHtml

Comment: Thanks for reply, Thunder. let me check and will get back to you.

Comment: Hi Thunder, I have tried that, it works fine when file taken from raw folder but on my requirement its gives exception :

Error processing zip file (is it a zip file?)

My inputstream comes from server while downnloading the file and same i am passing to activity:

WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = (WordprocessingMLPackage)loader.get(theInputStream);

But its not working.. Will you please guide me?

Comment: @Munish - mostly you can show if you file in your raw folder . 

Having said that ,when you are downloading the file from server , why dont you think about changing the file from .docx to .html or .pdf which you can very easily show in the WebViews.

Comment: Hi Thunder, previously it was giving issue as the jar this library is using has duplicate files. Somehow I managed to resolve them all in Android and its working fine. It takes little long time to display the DOCX document, But its working. Also, there is some jar which I modified and it worked. Thanks for your help. :)

Comment: Your welcome :) Yes , displaying Doc is little tricky but good to hear finally its done :)

Comment: hi i am using this demo but always getting error in WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = (WordprocessingMLPackage)loader.get(is) i have implements all jars but it seem not working to me any one have any idea EROR IS- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lsun/awt/AppContext